# Cannot connect to rails server on Fedora 21

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fedora

I started `rails server` but `http://192.168.56.104:3000` is not available. Its address is correct because I can see the test page of Apache at `http://192.168.56.104:80`.

I started the server:

```
$ rails s
Warning: Running `gem pristine --all` to regenerate your installed gemspecs (and deleting then reinstalling your bundle if you use bundle --path) will improve the startup performance of Spring.
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2015-03-10 09:45:49] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-03-10 09:45:49] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
[2015-03-10 09:45:49] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=5512 port=3000
```

Then it is working:

```
# wget http://localhost:3000; head index.html 
--2015-03-10 09:53:39--  http://localhost:3000/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:3000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 14935 (15K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html         100%[=================>]  14.58K  --.-KB/s   in 0.001s 

2015-03-10 09:53:39 (18.1 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [14935/14935]

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Ruby on Rails: Welcome aboard</title>
    <style media="screen">
      body {
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 25px;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
```

IP:

```
# ip r
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3  proto static  metric 1024 
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15 
192.168.56.0/24 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.56.104
```

Firewall settings are:

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all
FedoraServer (default, active)
  interfaces: enp0s3 enp0s8
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

and:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=FedoraServer --list-all
FedoraServer (default)
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client http ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

and:

```
# cat /etc/firewalld/services/http.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<service>
  <short>WWW (HTTP)</short>
  <description>HTTP is the protocol used to serve Web pages. If you plan to make your Web server publicly available, enable this option. This option is not required for viewing pages locally or developing Web pages.</description>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="3000"/>
  <port protocol="tcp" port="80"/>
</service>
```

I'm using Fedora 21.

```
# cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 21 (Twenty One)
```

What should I check and fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! I have to use `-b` for rails server to work on not only localhost.

```
$ rails s -b 0.0.0.0
```

It was changed: https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/28b014484a8ac0bbb388e7eaeeef159598ec64fc